# Ajax Cascading Drop Down works under Visual Studio Virtual Host but get method error 500 on IIS 7.0

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have downloaded the sample AJAX toolKit website.

When opened in Visual Studio 2012 everything works fine.

When I publish to IIS 7.0 Cascading Drop Down example gives method error 500.

I can browse to CarsService.asmx and invoke the GetDropDownContents method and get xml data returned so the service is working fine.

Suggestions?

I don't care if I use AJAX toolkit or not. I just want to create some webforms that populate data from an API.

Comment: Did you also publish the web service that feeds the Cascading Drop Down?

Comment: Fernando-yes I published the web service and know it works because I browsed to it and invoked it.

Answer (score 0):

[Used answer from this question to solve problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822733/ajaxtoolkit-iis7-asp-net-4-0-sys-is-not-defined-handler-mapping-issue)  I added following Code to my web.config file

```
  <system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers>
 <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
</handlers> </system.webServer>
```